# Add and remove items in ManyToMany relation in Django

Tags: python, django

I have model as follows:

```
class BusinessUnitGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    business_units = models.ManyToManyField(to=BusinessUnit, blank=True, null=True)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now in an view I have fields with group id's where the business unit needs to be added. From the other one it needs to be remove if it exists. I do it as follows:

```
business_unit = get_or_none(BusinessUnit, id=business_unit_id)

# Groups
old_groups = BusinessUnitGroup.objects.exclude(id__in=form_data['groups'])
for group in old_groups:
    group.business_units.remove(business_unit)

new_groups = BusinessUnitGroup.objects.filter(id__in=form_data['groups'])
for group in new_groups:
    group.business_units.add(business_unit)
```

Where `form_data['groups']` is an param and it's just a list of ids `[1, 2, 3]`

That works fine, but is there any better way to do it?

**UPDATE**

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def handle_edit_business_unit(form_data, company_id, business_unit_id):
    if not form_data:
        return {'result': 'nok', 'message': 'The form data is not provided.'}

    try:
        business_unit = get_or_none(BusinessUnit, id=business_unit_id)

        if business_unit:
            business_unit.name = form_data['name']
            business_unit.save()

            # Groups
            business_unit.businessunitgroup_set.set(form_data['groups'])
        

        return {'result': 'ok', 'message': ''}
    except Exception as err:
        # TODO Log error message somewhere
        print(str(err))
        return {'result': 'nok', 'message': 'The business unit could not be handled. Please try again.'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can work with [**`.set(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```
business_unit = get_or_none(BusinessUnit, id=business_unit_id)
business_unit.businessunitgroup_set.set(form_data['groups'])
```

We here thus work with the `ManyToManyField` in *reverse*. Instead of altering the `BusinessUnitGroup`s by removing or adding a `business_unit`. We simply set the `businessunitgroup_set`s of the `business_unit`.

By setting the many-to-many field that way, this normally should work with *two* queries: one to remove all the items not in `forms_data['groups']`, and one that adds the `form_data['groups']` to the `business_unit`.

Comment: I get the following error `'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'set'
`

Comment: @Boky: likely you work with the `BusinessUnitGroup.business_unitgroup_set`, but it should be the `business_unit` (so the model *object*), not a reference to the model class. If I use the class reference, I can reproduce your error, by using a `BusinessUnit` *object*, you should be able to work wit this.

Comment: I've update my question with the code that I have.

Comment: @Boky: can you edit the question with the *full* traceback?